# SQLite db protection using events/mutex

Tags: sqlite, events, mutex

I have two windows applications which will be accessing same database(stored in a hard disk). Only one of these two application is performing both read/write operations in this db while the second one only performs read operations. Do I need mutex/events to protect my db while both applications are accessing it? I was reading FAQ of SQLite which says that I might not need any resource protection, SQLite has in-built feature..